# Notificaciones Android tardan en llegar o se retrasan

Tags: android, firebase, notificaciones

Tengo una aplicacion con firebase desarrollada en Android studio, en la cual recibo notificaciones
todo va bien a exepcion de que las notificaciones tardan en llegar, igualmente por ejemplo durante las noches o durante que el celular no esta activo, las notificaciones llega pero no aparecen en pantalla, cuando activo el celular o desbloqueo la pantalla de repente me aparecen todas las notificaciones de golpe, de esto me doy cuenta en las mañanas por ejemplo: durante la noche recibo 20 notificaciones y no aparecen ni suenan si no hasta que desbloqueo mi celular es aqui donde suenan las 20noti (es algo molesto por que suena 20 veces), al observar el tiempo de la notificacion todas las 20 dicen "ahora" como si apenas acabaran de llegar, aunque en realidad llegaron en diferentes horas de la noche
que podria estar pasando? ya verifique que no este activo el ahorro de energia para esa app en mi celular

si la app esta abierta o minimizada, o estoy usando mi cel para otras cosas la notificacion llega casi al instante, aunque muchas veces con un retraso de 5min aproximadamente que podria estar pasando?

les comparto el codigo con el cual recibo la notificacion

```
type her    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        MostrarToken(token);
    }

    private void MostrarToken(String token) {
        Log.e("tokenf", "tokenfirebase" + token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        String mensaje = message.getFrom();
        Log.e("error-app", "Token msg" + mensaje);

        if (message.getData().containsKey("Title") && message.getData().containsKey("ObjectId") && message.getData().containsKey("Detalle")) {
            notiTitle = message.getData().get("Title");
            objectId = message.getData().get("ObjectId");
            notiDetalle = message.getData().get("Detalle");
            mayorOreo(notiTitle, notiDetalle, objectId);
        }
    }

    private void mayorOreo(String titulo, String detalle, String objectId) {
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.song);

        String id = "mensaje";
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);
        NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel(id, "nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();
        //personalizamos la notificacion
        nc.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
        nc.setShowBadge(true);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);

        int notifyId = generateNotificationId(objectId);
        notificationIdMap.put(objectId, notifyId); // Almacena el objectId y su notifyId correspondiente

        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentText(detalle)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(clickNoty(objectId, notifyId))
                .setContentInfo("Nuevo");

        assert nm != null;
        nm.notify(notifyId, builder.build());
    }

    public PendingIntent clickNoty(String objectId, int notifyId) {
        Intent intent;
        // ...
        String currentActivity= getTopActivityName(this);
        if (currentActivity == null) {
            intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            intent.putExtra("notificacionId", objectId);
            intent.putExtra("diClick", true);

        } else {
            if (currentActivity.equals("com.Login")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                intent.putExtra("diClick", true);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            } else {
                // Si no, lanza la ventana Detalle_alerta
                intent = new Intent(this, ListaAlertas.class);
                intent.putExtra("diClick", true);
                intent.putExtra("usuario_aplicacion", usuario_aplicacion_notificacion);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            }
        }

        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private int generateNotificationId(String objectId) {
        if (notificationIdMap.containsKey(objectId)) {
            return notificationIdMap.get(objectId);
        } else {
            // Si no existe un notifyId asociado a este objectId, genera uno nuevo
            int newId = notificationIdCounter++;
            notificationIdMap.put(objectId, newId);
            return newId;
        }
    }

    private String getTopActivityName(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (activityManager != null) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
            if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
                ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
                return topActivity.getClassName();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La velocidad de envío de notificaciones después de registrar tu dispositivo depende de Google, pero debes contemplar que para recibir las notificaciones es muy importante, tener conexión a internet en tu dispositivo.

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> "durante la noche recibo 20 notificaciones y no aparecen ni suenan si
> no hasta que desbloqueo mi celular es aqui donde suenan las 20noti (es
> algo molesto por que suena 20 veces), al observar el tiempo de la
> notificacion todas las 20 dicen "ahora" como si apenas acabaran de
> llegar, aunque en realidad llegaron en diferentes horas de la noche"

**La causa de esto es que de acuerdo a la configuración de algunos dispositivos, estos pueden apagar la antena de tu dispositivo, lo cual causaría que no tenga internet, al encenderse la antena y tener conexión a internet recibirías todas las notificaciones de forma continua, aunque estas fueron enviadas previamente a diferente hora, esto puede considerarse un comportamiento normal.**

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> "si la app está abierta o minimizada, o estoy usando mi cel para otras
> cosas, la notificación llega casi al instante, aunque muchas veces con
> un retraso de 5min aproximadamente que podría estar"

**Si tu dispositivo cuenta con conexión a internet, las notificaciones llegarán sin problema, como mencione inicialmente, el envío de las mismas es determinado por Google, incluso no importando si definiste [PRIORITY_HIGH](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels?hl=es-419#importance) a las mismas.**

Si defines para tus notificaciones [PRIORITY_HIGH](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels?hl=es-419#importance), lo cual indica asignar la más alta prioridad a tus notificaciones, tanto visual como en velocidad de envío, esto puede tener varios inconvenientes como son: Consumo de batería, interrupción al usuario, privacidad ya que se mostrarían en la pantalla, notificaciones intrusivas, etc. Incluso si abusas de esta propiedad, Google puede tratar tus notificaciones como notificaciones con prioridad predeterminada.

Te sugiero eliminar la prioridad

```
 .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

para definir una importancia predeterminada, a menos que estés seguro de que en verdad necesitas definir tu notificación como de alta prioridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion. La notificacion es sobre un incidente por lo que si requiero que sea prioridad alta para que los usuarios esten informados y puedan atender la emergencia lo mas rapido...pero probare como se comporta quitando la prioridad... Ahora lo raro del tema es que las notificaciones de otras apps como whatsapp face, etc por poner un ejemplo llegan bien con normalidad pero en mi desarollo mientras el cel esta suspendido estas no llegan.. como si el servicio en segundo plano de mi app se detubiera o si la notificacion llegara pero el sistema no la muestra hasta desbloque

Comment: Si en verdad necesitas que sea de prioridad alta configurala de esta forma, pero no deben ser muchas notificaciones con esta prioridad al mismo usuario. Ahora lo que entiendo es que entonces ¿no llegan solo las notificaciones de tu aplicación estando en segundo plano?

Comment: muchas gracias despues de revisar muy detalladamente la documentacion, existen tipos de mensajes de "notifcation" y de "data"
los mensajes de "notification" son administradas por el sistema (aqui si llegan aun con el telefono en reposo o con la pantalla bloqueada" aun tienen retrasos pero ya son mas cortos
y el tipo "data" estos mensajes los administra el metodo onMessageRecived y extienden del servicio de firebase, aqui las notificaciones no llegan cuando el celular entra en reposo, hasta que actives la pantalla y lo saques de ese estado
mi solucion fue utilzar los 2 "notification y "data"

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias despues de revisar muy detalladamente la documentacion, existen tipos de mensajes de "notifcation" y de "data" los mensajes de "notification" son administradas por el sistema (aqui si llegan aun con el telefono en reposo o con la pantalla bloqueada" aun tienen retrasos pero ya son mas cortos y el tipo "data" estos mensajes los administra el metodo onMessageRecived y extienden del servicio de firebase, aqui las notificaciones no llegan cuando el celular entra en reposo, hasta que actives la pantalla y lo saques de ese estado mi solucion fue utilzar los 2 "notification y "data"